# mysql joining not getting desired results

Tags: mysql

Below is my query basically there there is a studentsection table which contains student course info, this table has everything I need besides the course description. This is contained in the course table. For some reason I can't seem to just get just the entries from the studentsection table, every query I try gets everything from the course table. Any help is much appreciated!

```
select distinct studentid
              , s.deptnum
              , s.coursenum
              , coursedesc
              , sectionnum
              , quarter
              , grade 
           from studentsection c
           left 
           join course c
             on s.deptnum = c.deptnum 
          where exists( select deptnum from course) 
          order 
             by studentid
              , quarter
              , grade;
```

Here are my table definitions:

```
create table StudentSection(
    studentID int,
    deptNum char(4),
    courseNum char(3),
    sectionNum char(2),
    quarter char(3),
    grade varchar(1),
    constraint studentSection_PK primary key(studentID, deptNum, courseNum, sectionNum, quarter),
    constraint studentSection_section_FK foreign key (deptNum, courseNum, sectionNum, quarter) references Section(deptNum, courseNum, sectionNum, quarter)
)

CREATE TABLE Course (
    deptNum    char(4),
    courseNum  char(3),
    courseDesc varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    creditHrs integer,
    CONSTRAINT course_PK PRIMARY KEY (deptNum, courseNum),
    CONSTRAINT course_department_FK FOREIGN KEY (deptNum) REFERENCES department(deptNum))

CREATE TABLE Section (
    deptNum     char(4),
    courseNum   char(3),
    sectionNum  char(2),
    quarter     char(3),
    instructor  varchar(20),
    CONSTRAINT section_PK PRIMARY KEY (deptNum, courseNum, sectionNum, quarter),
    CONSTRAINT section_course_FK FOREIGN KEY (deptNum, courseNum) REFERENCES course(deptNum, courseNum));
```

Comment: Are you joining on the right field? Is `deptnum` a `PRIMARY KEY` for `course`? Could you please post your tables definitions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got your problem right, but did you try an `inner join`?